# UISegmented Control color breaks on last segment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I seem to be having an issue with UISegmented control breaking it's color on the last segment. Here is an example

[image]

I use UIStoryboard to setup my segmented control but for the color changing and border radius this is what i am using

```
_segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
_segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[_segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
[_segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[Painter imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[_segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[Painter imageWithColor:_segmentedControl.tintColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And for additional information on what imageWithColor is doing here is the function for that

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithColor:(UIColor*)color{
   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0, 2.0);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
   CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
   UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return image;
}
```

Comment: You mean the little white on the right side of the control? Do you also see it on the left when 10% is selected?

Comment: I do not also see it on the left when 10% i selected

Answer (score 0):

I've used your same code and this is the result:

[image]

There is no white border.

I'm using XCode 9.2 with iOS11 iPhoneX simulator.

You can try to change your code

```
_segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

to:

```
_segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

If the issue keep staying you can try with the same mine configuration and if it keep on we can try to find the solution.

**EDIT**:

Ok, I've tried with your width and I can reproduce the issue but I can reproduce it ONLY if I set the proportional width.

This because the proportional width can set the width size with decimal number, what we see is the decimal part of the size.

The good news is that it seems to be only a simulator issue, I have deployed the project in an iPhone and it does not reproduce.

You can try it in  the size inspector of IB changing the proportional width until in the "view width" you can see an integer number without decimal.

Comment: Ok i am trying this now

Comment: So even when i change the borderColor to clearColor i still get the same results. I'm using xcode 9.2 with an iphone 8 simulator as well as a test device. The width of my segmneted device is = to the width of screen with a multiplier of 0.7

Comment: I just tested by creating another project, and it doesn't seem to have this issue. So there must be some side of affect of the controller that it's on....

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it, because you also have to think there is different screen sizes. I Was able to reproduce the exact same code on a different project with no issues. So like i said in my above comment it could be a side affect of the controller?

Comment: The solution is independent from the screen size, you just have to check the segmented control size. You can test it without a proportional width but with a fixed size.